# mac osx webcam for avd of nexus 7

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator, osx-mountain-lion, eclipse-juno

Below is a screenshot of my AVD. But right now it does not use the camera on my laptop. So I changed `Front camera` from `Simulated` to `Webcam0`; except, after that when I run an app the AVD Emulator does not show up at all. After I edit back to `Emulated`, the emulator shows up.

Is it possible to use my laptop's camera with the emulator? My computer is osx mountain lion.

[image: Nexus 7 AVD]